# Why can't I edit my own deleted (hidden) question?

Tags: support, feature-request, editing, deleted-questions

There was an issue in my last question on Math.Stackexchange.  I wanted to first formulate the general idea of my question, and then work on the question a little bit.  It would be ideal if I could do this (i.e., edit the question) when the question is deleted (hidden), so other users do not have to respond and potentially get confused by the active editing.  I know that Meta's Sandbox is an option, but why can't we edit deleted questions as we can with deleted answers?  I think this should be a feature.

**Edit.**  For clarification, it was a self-deleted question.  I still think that editing a self-deleted question should still be a feature.  To prevent spammers, this might be a feature that users with reputations higher than some lower bound can earn the right to edit self-deleted questions.

Comment: You usually *can* edit deleted questions of your own. Do you have a link? (Actually I'm not entirely sure, if I'm editing something deleted its generally an answer.)

Comment: I removed the feature request and turned it into a support question. Given that it is specifically designed to apply to self-deleted posts, which possibly was not clear when you asked, it is not realistic as a feature request, but feel free to restore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the main Meta post of [Why can I not edit a self-deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296101/562482) says the restriction is just for self-deleted questions:

> Posts that are deleted, but not **self-deleted** can be edited without restriction.

It also says the main reason for this restriction is to help prevent a form of abuse by spammers that is "very difficult for the system to counter".

As you can see in the "Linked" section on the right of that Meta post, there are requests to change this behavior, such as in [Let me edit my own self-deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327788/562482) and [Let me edit my own deleted post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6347/562482). However, as far as I know, there are no official company statements about even looking into this further, much less any plans to change how this works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I think the least they could do to prevent spans is maybe allowing users with sufficiently high reputations to edit their self-deleted questions.  Of course, we have no say in this matter, unfortunately.